# Help unmounting a disk image

Tags: mount, iso

I mounted two iso files with Furius ISO mount, and then, forgetting about them, closed ISO mount, and shut down my laptop. Now, they won't unmount. They say fstab missing/you are not root.
Please help?!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output from the console of `mount`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Thanks to Braiam I typed `mount` into the Terminal and checked the mounting point of the unwanted image in the output - in my case it was /home/my_username/the_unwanted_file - and then typed

```
sudo umount /home/my_username/the_unwanted_file
```

into the Terminal and worked like a charm for me. I hope it helps.

P.S. (Note that it's "Umount", not "UNmount" ;)